# Deleting Rows Based off of Column Values - But not just one Column Value - A lis of values

Tags: python, pandas

I understand this example below to delete a row if a column contains "XYZ":

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[5,3,5,6], C=["foo","bar","fooXYZbar", "bat"]))
In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   A          C
0  5        foo
1  3        bar
2  5  fooXYZbar
3  6        bat

In [93]: df[df.C.str.contains("XYZ") == False]
Out[93]:
   A    C
0  5  foo
1  3  bar
3  6  bat
```

But what if you wanted it to delete the row if the column contained anything inside of another dataframes column so lets say we had a second data frame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=["XYZ","ABC","EFg","6","foo"], C=["test","bar","testABC", "ba6t"]))
```

so I would want to do something list this ( note the pusedo code)

```
df[df.C.str.contains(df2.'Column A') == False]
```

If df column C contains anything that is inside of df2 column A , delete the row in df

Comment: If I understand your problem properly then you need to the following, First find unique in df2 and store this in list then pass a regex in your above code. So, that it will remove all the values from df1 based on the df2 values.

Comment: I don’t think you understand it quite right my bad. I don’t need anything unique from df2. Just for the df coulumn C to lookup if anything in df2 column exists. Then delete the rows where it does exist.

Comment: finding unique elements in df2 only for performance. If your df2 contains duplicate records, It's useful to take unique, I have updated this as answer please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
l=df2['A'].unique().tolist()
reg='|'.join(l)
print df1[df1['C'].str.contains(reg)==False]
```

Output:

```
   A    C
1  3  bar
3  6  bat
```

For NaN removal

```
l=df2[df2['A'].notnull()]['A'].unique().tolist()
```

Comment: hello, this worked with my example, but with my exact spread sheet, I got "TypeError: sequence item 3071: expected str instance, float found" Any idea on a quick fix for that? I tried l = str(l)

Comment: @pes04 - This error because your column contains mixed data type. convert your column into str then try the same, it should work

Comment: thank you for all your help Mohamed Thasin, the probelm now is when I open my excel sheeet , it is completely blank, I pasted my live code in your comments

Comment: Yeah, if you have a blank rows then it considered as a float, remove blank records before converting into list. then do the above it will work

Comment: using i = str(i) made the code run, just when my results.xlsx opens it is all blank - is that what you are describing above in your last comment to be the issue?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 3135: expected str instance, int found

Comment: That is the error I just got, pasting in my code to your comment now

Comment: I think your contains still has a mixed datatype isssue, It's hard to understand the problem without viewing the data. For now you could try this, `l=df2['A'].astype(str).unique().tolist()`

Comment: all of the data is this W596304 ( it stats with a W and has 6 numbers after) that I am looking up. Essentially I am trying to circumvent doing a vlookup./group the vlookup matches and delete all the rows that had a match in the vlookup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180036/discussion-between-mohamed-thasin-ah-and-pes04).

Comment: So all there are 1000 different combinations of W123456 in df1 Column A, and I am finding all the same values of W123456 in df2 Column A (there are about 400 of the same) and deleting those same from the 1000, to have a remainder  of 6000 or so

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this , since `contains` accept `'|'`

```
df[~df.C.str.contains('|'.join(df2.A.tolist()))]
Out[65]: 
   A    C
1  3  bar
3  6  bat
```